# How to solve " Cannot resolve method getAssets()" in Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to use getAssets(). at Android Studio, but it doesn't works. 
I made this file for parsing the JSON data.
How can I solve it??

**JsonParseData.java**

```
package com.example.naviforyou;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class JsonDataParse<SeoulData> {

private String getJsonString() {
    String json = "";

    try {
        //
        InputStream is = getAssets().open("SeoulData.json");
        int fileSize = is.available();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[fileSize];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();

        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return json;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getAssets() is a method of a context , so :
make this class accepts a context object , set it to a member context then you can invoke getAssets() from context member variable

you can either pass a context to a class constructor of have the method getJsonString(Context context) accept one. then you call contxt.getAssets()